# NSDictionary. How to create NSDictionary object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have this method.

```
[self postRequestWithURL: (NSString *) postArgs:(NSDictionary *) headerArgs: (NSDictionary *) ];
```

How can I correctly call this method?

the url is: `http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?`

the post args are: `"a=user/-/state/com.google/read&ac=edit-tags&s=feed/%@&i=%@&T=%@", entry.link, entry.identifier, tokenString`

and header are:

```
NSString *authHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin %@", authString];
[thttpReq addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[thttpReq addValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
```

Can sompne help me to insert postArgs and HeaderArgs in a `NSDictionary`?
Thanks
Paolo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSDictionary *postArgs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                            @"user/-/state/com.google/read", @"a",
                            @"edit-tags", @"ac",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat: @"feed/%@", entry.link], @"s",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", entry.identifier], @"i",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", tokenString], @"T",
                            nil];

NSDictionary *headerArgs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             [NSString stringWithFormat: @"GoogleLogin %@", authString], @"Authorization",
                             @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Content-Type"
                             nil];

[self postRequestWithURL: @"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag"
                postArgs: postArgs
              headerArgs: headerArgs];
```

Note that the list after `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` contains alternations of objects and keys, separated by commas, followed by a final `nil`, as in the example above.

FWIW, the dictionaries here are autoreleased, so you don't have to release them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by reading [**NSDictionary**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [**NSMutableDictionary**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. Here's how you'd do it:

```
NSString * feed = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"feed/%@&i=%@&T=%@", entry.link, entry.identifier, tokenString];
NSDictionary * parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"a", @"user/-/state/com.google/read", @"ac", @"edit-tags", @"s", feed, nil];
```

Comment: see my answer. I think `Content-Type` is the key and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the value, and not the other way around.